# Initialize plugin in self-invoking function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to set up a pagination on my website and I found a JavaScript plugin to do this.

I need to initalize plugin in self-invoking function, like this:

```
$(function(){

    $('#pagination').twbsPagination({
        visiblePages: 3,
        totalPages: 10,
        prev: '<<',
        next: '>>',
        first: '',
        last: '',
        pageClass: 'page-item page-item-w',
        onPageClick: function (event, page){
            ..............
        }
    });

});
```

But an error appears in console:

```
TypeError: $(...).twbsPagination is not a function
```

When I put initialization outside from self-invoke function than It works:

```
$('#pagination').twbsPagination({
    visiblePages: 3,
    totalPages: 10,
    prev: '<<',
    next: '>>',
    first: '',
    last: '',
    pageClass: 'page-item page-item-w',
    onPageClick: function (event, page){
        ..............
    }
});

$(function(){

    // ............

});
```

How to initalize this in self-invoking function?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an IIFE there. That's the `$` function which you are passing another function to as a callback. It will call that function when the DOM Ready event fires.

Something is happening between the point where you are putting the code and the DOM Ready firing which stops `$.twbsPagination` from existing.

Typically that is:

1. Loading jQuery
2. Loading the plugin into jQuery
3. Loading jQuery **again** overwriting the first one and the plugins attached to it

Don't load jQuery multiple times in one document.